# How to force Qt to update GUI from not main thread

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm fighing since last week with problem caused by update of QPlainTextEdit. I'm trying to create separate from QMainWindow Dialog window with QPlainTextEdit inside. The problem begins when I try to use appendHtml signal (also tried with appendText), text that is placed is not visible unless marked by by mouse. Repainting or updating cause in program crash or no visible action.

Simplified code of QDialog with QPlainTextEdit header:

```
namespace Ui {
class LogWindow;
}

class LogWriter: public QDialog
{   
Q_OBJECT

QMutex print_lock;

public:

class Log{

    Q_OBJECT

    const static int MAX_SIZE = 100;
    bool to_terminal;
    QString color;
    QMutex *print_lock;
    QPlainTextEdit *text_place;
    QVector< QPair<QString,time_t> > history;
    LogWriter * obj;

    public:
    bool print;

    Log(bool _print,QString _color,LogWriter *obj_ = NULL)
    {print = _print; color = _color; obj = obj_;}
    void setLock(QMutex *print_lock_){print_lock = print_lock_;}
    void setTextField(QPlainTextEdit *_text) {text_place = _text;}
    Log& operator<<(QString &a);
    Log& operator<<(const char* a);
};

static LogWriter* getInstance()
{
    static LogWriter    instance; // Guaranteed to be destroyed.
                              // Instantiated on first use.
    return &instance;
}
~LogWriter();

Log LOW,MEDIUM,HIGH;
Ui::LogWindow *ui;

signals:
void signalLogAppend(QString);
};
```

Simplified code of methods definitions:

```
LogWriter::LogWriter(QWidget * parent): QDialog(parent) {

ui = new Ui::LogWindow;
ui->setupUi(this);

LOW.setLock(&print_lock);
MEDIUM.setLock(&print_lock);
HIGH.setLock(&print_lock);

connect(this,SIGNAL(signalLogAppend(QString)),ui->plainTextEdit, 
SLOT(appendHtml(QString)),Qt::DirectConnection);

}

LogWriter::Log& LogWriter::Log::operator<< (QString &s){
history.push_front(qMakePair(s,time(NULL)));
if(history.size() > MAX_SIZE) history.pop_back();

if(print){
    //print_lock->lock();

    QString text = "<font color=\"";
    text += color + "\">";
    text += s + "</font>";
    //cout << text.toStdString() << endl;
    //text_place->appendHtml(text);
    //text_place->repaint();
    emit (obj)->signalLogAppend(text);
    //print_lock->unlock();

}
return *this;
}
```

I have two separate ui files (first for main window, second for log window).
I have to use log window all across my program (something about 10 threads), and I stucked on this issue. My question is - is it possible to force GUI update without using main thread and if not - what else possibilities I have. If possible I would rather avoid reconstructing all my code - it would take me some time to do it. Right now logging is super easy - I ony need:

```
 LogWindow *log = LogWindow::getInstance();
 log->MEDIUM << "something";
```

As additional info I add QTCreator warning:

```
   QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextBlock'
   (Make sure 'QTextBlock' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
   QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextCursor'
   (Make sure 'QTextCursor' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, you're trying to log from a background thread and are using a direct connection to pass the signal to the GUI thread? That's not going to work, you have to send the signal via the default connection so Qt can figure out that it's a cross-thread signal and pass it across threads accordingly (ie, via the message loop on the foreground thread).

In Qt, any GUI interaction has to happen in the Main/foreground thread otherwise bad things happen as you discovered. You can certainly send a signal from a background thread to trigger a GUI update - I do this all the time - but you need to ensure that you're using the correct connection for it. The direct connection results in a direct function call and is not going to work for you in this case.

In your code, the problem is the call to [connect()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#connect%60) - you explicitly specify the connection mode for the signal to slot connection when you should just use the default setting. If you set the connection explicitly to `Qt::DirectConnection`, the underlying code will execute a direct call to the specified slot, which means that you end up calling the slot in the thread context of the signal. You don't want that because the signal is triggered in a background thread.

Comment: Yes - I'm trying to log from a background thread (even many threads - by operator<<), but I don't use direct call (or maybe I'm wrong) I use signal to this - just like in code I attached.     "Send signal via the default connection" - what does it mean ? Also rest of this sentence is rather blurr to me.

Comment: What he means is in your LogWritter class connection you call connect(....) with 5 arguments. Remove the 5th argument Qt:DirectConnection. Direct connections are only for same thread connections. Either remove the argument and let Qt figure out that  it needs to be Qt:QueuedConnection or just mention it yourself. I find it better to be explicit in connections for cross thread signal-slot

Comment: OMG it works.... how could I miss that, four days of searching, while I could just check what QT::directconnection boundaries are ... Thanks very much for help !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass arbitrary types/classes to signals and slots. The list is limited and not all Qt classes are in the list. To add types/classes to the list of those that can be passed to a signal/slot, you must call qRegisterMetaType for that class. I recommend calling it in the constructor of the class you're trying to pass to a signal like this:

```
MyClass::MyClass() : MyParentClass()
{
    static int reg = qRegisterMetaType<MyClass>("MyClass");
}
```

The static int ensures the registration is only called once and before any instance of MyClass could ever be used.